# PHP changing old mysql for PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im starting to learn PDO, and Im trying to convert an old code of mine into PDO but Im not having sucess here.

This is my old code,

```
$countViews = "SELECT SUM(table_views) AS views from posts";
$exeViews = mysql_query($countViews) or die('Error');
$views = 0;
$table_views= mysql_result($exeViews,$views,"views");
if($table_views >=1 )
{
    $table_views= $table_views;
}
else
{
    $table_views= 0;
}
```

I want to Sum the views in my table_views column, so I use the Sum in my column from my posts table,

then I execute my query, then I´ll determine that my $views to start count at 0, and my $table_vies will get the result of the count with mysql_result.

How I can use mysql_result in $pdo? Im trying to  find information but I dont find nothing that works!

Im trying like this, but now is missing the hard part (mysql_result):

```
$countViews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(table_views) AS views from posts");
$countViews->execute();
$views = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// you do not need $views = 0
$table_views = $countViews->fetchColumn();
```

[PDO::fetchColumn()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) and read about other fetching.

Comment: Thank you, it worked and the link you gave me explains very well this!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) your result:

```
$row = $countViews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$table_views = $row['views'];
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer also worked! But it seems that I cant accept both answers in this site :/

Comment: @user3533979: Nope, you can't accept both answers. But you can upvote both (using the up arrow above the number) if they were useful. Not begging for upvotes here, just letting you know how the site works.

Comment: Thanks but it says that I need reputation 15 to do that!